# Plotting Vector field of a point charge

Tags: matlab, vector

I have been trying to model the electric field of a point charge using the quiver command.

```
x=-5:0.5:5;
y=-5:0.5:5;
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
r=(xx.^2+yy.^2).^0.5;
quiver(x,y,xx./r^3, yy./r^3,1);
```

The resultant electric field is as follows, 
[image]

As you can see the length of the vector increases as you move away from the charge (center). I learned the length of the vector plotted by quiver depends on the magnitude of the vector at that point. Since the electric field reduces as you move away, one would expect the length of the vector should reduce away from the charge. I tried to understand this or remedy this but I could not find anything.

Can anyone explain why this is happening or how this can be fixed.

Thanks for your time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple fix actually. You just forgot two dots.

```
x=-5:0.5:5;
y=-5:0.5:5;
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
r=(xx.^2+yy.^2).^0.5;
quiver(x,y,xx./r.^3, yy./r.^3,1);  %% <---  Note the additional . in front of ^
```

[image]